ArcGIS GP service slowing down
Wondering if anyone has experienced something similar or knows of a solution to my problem.
I have created a geoprocessing service on one of our ArcGIS Servers and it’s scheduled to run every 15 minutes.
Essentially what the service does is it takes a CSV of about 6000 records reads it in a data frame and carries out some pandas transformation, plots the data using convert coordinate notation, carries out a spatial join with some field mapping, deletes all rows from the existing database, appends the data in and that’s it.
The feature class is in an enterprise geodatabases on SQL Server and I write the CSV to a temp file the intermediate processes are written in memory up until the append.
Initially the script took about 45 seconds to run but increasingly went up in time.
After reading online that it can cause fragmentation in the database from appending so many times, I created a script to carry out some database maintenance tasks - compress / Rebuild indexes / analyse dataset. This appeared to work for a day or two but then the script started to creep back up in time.
I can’t share my script unfortunately as its locked away on a company system.

If you run your maintenance scripts daily, or at least weekly, does that keep the GP service runtime down?

So I created the feature class in the DB about a month ago, which the script writes into, and it’s slowly increased in time since. I hadn’t been running the db maintenance script during this period. But it went up like a hockey stick the past week. So I created the maintenance script and ran it yesterday. It brought the time down from 9 minutes down to about 4 minutes. Which was kind of acceptable. But then again today it went back up to 9 minutes shortly before I left work

Just to add the database isn’t versioned or archiving enabled
